# How to create POJO class for xml parse in java?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, pojo

I got exact output what I need, but I have to use POJO class for my program, I searched lot for issue, but I didnt get clear idea.Help me to solve this issue,thanks in advance, my coding for xml pharse in java given below.

Coding for ReadAndPrintXMLFile::

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ReadAndPrintXMLFile{
    public static void main (String argv []){


    try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            URL url = new URL("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            InputStream stream = url.openStream();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(stream);

            // normalize text representation
            doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
            System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " +
                 doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("head");
            int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total no of head : " + totalPersons);
            for(int s=0; s<listOfPersons.getLength() ; s++){
                Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
                if(firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element firstPersonElement = (Element)firstPersonNode;
                    //-------
                    NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("heading");
                    Element firstNameElement = (Element)firstNameList.item(0);
                    NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("Heading : " +
                           ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                }//end of if clause
            }//end of for loop with s var
        }catch (SAXParseException err) {
        System.out.println ("** Parsing error" + ", line "
             + err.getLineNumber () + ", uri " + err.getSystemId ());
        System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage ());
        }catch (SAXException e) {
        Exception x = e.getException ();
        ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace ();
        }catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace ();
        }
        //System.exit (0);
    }//end of main
}
```

For this xml parse program I  have to POJO class, .So For this I create a class like this

```
public class POJOurl {

    private String heading;

    public String getHeading() {
        return heading;
    }

    public void setHeading(String heading) {
        this.heading = heading;
    }


}
```

Here I dont know how to use thse get and set method in my program, using these public String getHeading() and public void setHeading(String heading) I have to execute the program.. and I have to get the output what I am getting now.. only thing is I have to use POJO class for this program

Output::

```
Root element of the doc is root1
Total no of head : 4
Heading : Appliance Repairs
Heading : Air conditioning and refrigeration services
Heading : Accountants
Heading : Accident Management
```

Comment: What is your specific issue/problem ?

Comment: I have to create POJO class( (ie) using get and set method i have to generate output) and from that class I have to get output,

Comment: This XML you are reading - is it written against an XSD?

Comment: @user1443848 I may be way off but do you need something that will read an XML file into a POJO class? If so you should take a look at Jaxb an the like. In any case I think kjp is right by saying an XSD would help if you have one.

Comment: Try JAXB http://jaxb.java.net/guide/

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class Person with the attributes that you need, e.g. firstName.

Comment: hmmm.. I created                                               private String heading;
 public String getHeading() {
  return heading;
 }
 public void setHeading(String heading) {
  this.heading = heading;
 }   But I dont know how to call these set and get method and where I have to call .. Since I am new to POJO I am getting confusion over here..

Comment: Can you tell us what your output should look like.

Comment: I am getting my output exactly what I what.. but I didnt use POJO class, I want the same output what I am getting now, but I have to use POJO class through that I need to get output.

Comment: I think you need to understand what POJO means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object. If you have a clear understanding of the concept I'm sure you'll find your homework to be relatively simple.